# MFC CComboBoxEx select text only

Tags: mfc, ccombobox

I am using the `CComboBoxEx` control in MFC to select color for future drawing. Items in my ComboBox have small pictures – examples of color, and color names. Everything is Ok, except one annoying thing – when I select some item, not only text in selected item has different background, but the picture itself is changed. How to change only background color of text?

[image: Example of selected item in picture]

[image: ComboBox lost focus - item displays normally]

Comment: Please show the code where you set the background color.

Comment: It is not I who set the background color, it is normal behavior of ComboBox - when you select any item from the drop down list, and it is displayed in ComboBox as selected with background color (blue, as usual). Please, look at Environment / Fonts and Colors dialog window activated by Tools / Options in Microsoft Visual Studio. When you select any color in ComboBox, this item becomes selected, text background color becomes blue, but small picture with stays the same.

Comment: As you can check with MS Spy++ Visual Studio has set `CBS_OWNERDRAWFIXED` for the control that you mention. So that might be the way to solve it, but that means you have to do all the drawing yourself.